# unable to break a list with finite size

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with letters:

```
list1 = [abcdefghijk]
```

I have `num = 3` and want to break `list1` in parts of 3, i.e:

```
[[abc], [def], [ghi], [jk]]
```

My code is:

```
for i in range(0, len(list1), num):
    chunks = [list1[i:i+num]]
```

I get wrong output:

```
chunks = ['k']
```

But I expect:

```
chunks = [[abc],[def],[ghi],[jk]]
```

I have gone through all the available solutions here. But they did not help. How should I fix this?

Comment: you should put letters in quotes, otherwise it is not a legal structure in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> list2 = 'abcdefghijk'
>>> [list2[i:i+num] for i in range(0, len(list2), num)]
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

#### How it works

`i:i+num` is a slice: it selects starting at index `i` and continuing up to but not including index `i+num`.  For example:

```
>>> list2[6 : 6+3]
'ghi'
```

We want to perform slices every three characters.  To get the `i` values that we need, we use the `range` function:

```
>>> range(0, len(list2), num)
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Now, we want to slice list at each of the indices supplied by `range`.  Thus:

```
>>> [ list2[i:i+num] for i in range(0, len(list2), num) ]
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

This form is called *list comprehension*.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you don't need to put the string in a list since it's an iterable, and if it's so you can get it out and out the string in a variable and use python grouper function from [`itertools-recipes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to grouping your string with chunks and then use a list comprehension to join them :

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=''):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

[''.join(i) for i in grouper(list1,3)]
```

produces

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

**Note**: for python 3 use `zip_longest` instead

Comment: You should probably pass the `fillvalue` when you call grouper and leave `fillvalue=fillvalue`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Indeed thanks ;-)

Comment: pure genius to use the very same iterator repeatedly. I have learnt something today. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite the value stored in the variable `chunks` in every iteration of your loop. Therefore your solution is not working, this could be solved to adjust your code in the following way:

```
list1 = 'abcdefghijk'
chunks = []
for i in range(0, len(list1), num):
    chunks.append( list1[i:i+num] )
```

A more pythonic way of solving your problem is the following one-liner:

```
[list1[i:i+num] for i in range(0, len(list1), num)]
```

This is called [list comprehension](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=list%20comprehension%20python).

Comment: please avoid naming lists `list`, it will shadow the built-in name. BTW, aren't your solutions present among the answers already?

Comment: the other answers lack any explanation, but good point

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
num = 3
chunks = []
for i in range(0,len(list1), num):
      chunks.append([list1[i:i+num]])
print chunks
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, with no indexes and one pass only

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
num = 3
chunks = []
chunk = ''

for pos, el in enumerate(list1, 1):
    chunk += el
    if not pos % num:
        chunks.append(chunk)
        chunk = ''
chunks.append(chunk)

print chunks
```

produces

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```